# Help for the proof of Lemma for pull-backs

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

I am learning category theory from the book by Steve Awodey, trying to complete all the proofs, and I got stuck at one.

[image: Diagram]

> **Lemma**: Given the diagram above, if the square at the right and the rectangles are pull-back diagrams, then so is the square at the left.

In the book, Awodey says that the proof is done by "diagram chase", but I encounter a difficulty.

---

**My progress**:
Here is where I got so far.

Suppose there is a diagram $A \leftarrow_{\pi_1} X \rightarrow_{\pi_2} E$ such that $f\pi_1 = h'\pi_2$. To show that the left square is a pull back you need to show that there exists a unique morphism $u:X\rightarrow D$ such that $h''u = \pi_1$ and $f'u =\pi_2$.

Using the pull-back property of $D$ in the rectangle, you infer that there exists a unique morphism $x:X\rightarrow D$ such that $h''x =\pi_1$ and $g'f'x = g'\pi_2$. So $x$ looks like a good candidate.

Bearing this in mind, you use the pull-back property of $E$ in the right square to show that $\pi_2$ is the unique morphism $X \rightarrow E$ such that $h' \pi_2 = f \pi_1$.

Now,  **assuming that $fh''=h'f'$** , you can show
\begin{equation*}
h'(f'x) = fh''x = f\pi_1
\end{equation*}

and thus $f'x = \pi_2$.

This would complete the proof, but I cannot prove the highlighted assumption.

---

So the proof is, up to now, mostly diagram chase, but I cannot get that commutation down. Do I need to assume the square is commutative, or is there a way to infer it from the given assumptions?

Comment: Also, if you can recommend *en passant* a text with a (little) more conceptual discussions but comparable depth as Awodey's, please do so!

Comment: I assume you mean $fh'' = h'f'$. It's common to require diagrams to be commutative, so I'd say you can just take this as one of the givens.

Comment: Thanks @aes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed proof given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pullback_Lemma), together with all the relevant diagrams.

Comment: Indeed, it assumes the commutativity of the diagram on the onset.

Comment: I don't have the book on me right now, but doesn't Awodey state that the diagram is commutative?

Comment: Yes, he does u.u' . I didn't have the book on me either when I was trying to figure out the proof!